# Can you transfer GB(C) Pokemon from Red, Blue, Yellow, Gold, Silver, and Crystal to their respective 3DS Virtual Console counterparts?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green, pokemon-gold-silver-crystal, virtual-console, game-boy

Like the title suggests, I am wondering if there is any way to transfer my beloved Pokemon from the Gen 1/2 games to the VC games so I can get them to Bank, Home, and eventually Let's Go, Sw/Sh, and Bd/Sp.  However, I can't find a thing on the internet about this.  Maybe I'm just an idiot and not looking hard enough, but I really want to know how since I don't see any link cables that adapt GB(C) to 3DS.

Comment: I guess it does, but I am looking to transfer from Red Blue Yellow to Red Blue Yellow (or Gold Silver Crystal to Gold Silver Crystal).  Plus there is the fact that I dont have the tools to do that.

Comment: I've added a comment to the answer in the linked question that addresses transferring from different games. However, this does require Homebrew. Without external tools, it is not possible to transfer form cartridge to virtual console.